# Who assigns a private IP address to my laptop?

Tags: networking, ip

I am connected to a Wi-Fi network through my laptop. The Wi-Fi is from a mobile device.

1. In this case, does the mobile acts as a router?
2. Who assigns my laptop its private IP address?
3. Does my laptop have a public IP address?
4. Is the private IP address of my laptop the same as the private IP address of my mobile?
5. Can I change the private IP address of my laptop and be connected to the same Wi-Fi?
6. Is the private IP address assigned to my mobile by the ISP?
7. If I connect multiple devices to same Wi-Fi, do they have same private IP address?
8. If private IP addresses are the same within the Wi-Fi network, how does it identify different devices?
9. If I go to "settings" in my mobile it shows its IP address as 100.96.79.125. Is this the private address or public IP address? A private IP address assigned by the ISP or hardcoded? Will it have the public IP address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In this case the mobile acts as a router??

It actually does.

> Who assigns my laptop it's private ip address?

The phone does – it runs a DHCP server, just like a "full" home router would, and the laptop gets the address through a DHCP lease.

> Is the private ip address of laptop the same as private ip address of my mobile?

No. They're within the same subnet, though, but they're separate devices and both have their own unique addresses in that subnet.

> Can i change the private ip address of my laptop and be connected to the same wifi??

As long as the new address is still within the same subnet, and doesn't accidentally conflict with the router (i.e. the phone) or some other connected device – yes.

> Does my laptop has public ip address?

No. It'll *appear to* have one when accessing Internet sites, but the translation (NAT) is done within the router (i.e. the phone) – the laptop is actually unaware of it.

> If private IP addresses are same within the wifi network how does it identify different devices?

They're not the same.

> If i go to settings in mobile it shows IP address as 100.96.79.125 is it private address or public ip address ?

It's a private address (from the special 100.64.0.0/10 range that's specifically meant for assignment by ISPs rather than home networks).

Most mobile operators only assign this type of address – and even many fixed-connection ISPs are no longer assigning public addresses.

> Will it have public ip address

In your case no, same as above. The routers at your ISP will also perform NAT and automatically translate the phone's address to a public one, allowing connections to Internet, but that public address doesn't actually belong to the phone itself. It may even be shared between several customers.

(A phone *could* have a public IP address in theory, but I don't think there are any mobile operators which assign one anymore. Our Tele2 actually used to do this, but I think even they switched to CGNAT and private addresses last year...)